# Query regarding assert in JUnit

Tags: unit-testing, junit

All,

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of assertXXX () in Junit. Currently, I have a method `A(String fileName)` that is generating a xml file for a input `filename` "XXX.XX" . So my test case includes testing if the code is generating any file and not just XML file which is wrong i.e. method A should only generate xml files.

My code is:

```
testCreateFile()
{
     String fileName = "testFile.csv";
     A(fileName);
     File fileObj = new File (fileName);
     assertFalse(fileObj.exists()); // Since I check if the file should not be created

}
```

If I do this, I get an AssertionError and jUnit window shows 2 Failures. Do I have to handle this Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if A creates a file, don't you want to assertTrue?  In other words, you expect to find the file after you run A.  And then you assert that the content of the file is the expected xml...

If an exception is a failure, you don't need to handle the exception.

Comment: Well, my actual code does checking of the extension using fileName.indexOf(".xml") . But, for the above code posted, A should not have created a .csv file and hence I expect assertFalse() to work fine.

Comment: ah i see.  What exactly is the question then? What errors are you getting?

Comment: My question was that assertFalse () was giving me this AssertionError and if I use assertTrue() , there would be no errors. Basically, I was finding it difficult to understand how to use assert functions. Should it be used to test valid information passed or invalid information passed.

Comment: @darkie15 you should do both.  you can assert that something is true, or that something is false, that something is not null, or that something is null.  It depends on what your expectations are.

Comment: @darkie15, very good.  what was the issue?  I don't feel I really answered a question, but sometimes just bouncing an idea of someone can help a dev resolve the issue...